# Syncing editing between two Vim windows

Tags: vim, language-agnostic, editor

Is there a way to edit the same file in two different vim windows, and have changes synchronize live between the two?

The reason I want to have two windows for the same file is so that I can look at two different parts at the same time, and possibly edit both.

Background: I'm using the iTerm on Mac OSX to house the multiple windows.  These vim tabs are launched separately, by calling vim [file] each time.

Comment: I have the feeling that babonk is talking about GUI windows, the kind with close/maximise/minimize buttons. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Well, separate vim sessions don't talk to each other in that way. If you want to do this, you have to use *one* vim session.

Answer (score 4):

Vim does this naturally if you use its built-in window support. Use `:help window` to find out more (or see the [window documentation online](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html)). In a nutshell:

```
^W^N   create a new window
^W^W   switch between windows
^W^C   close a window
```

If you open the same file in two windows, updates will be reflected in each window as you type. There are commands for splitting both horizontally and vertically, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, there is one option: `scrollbind` which synchronizes both windows.

Open files in vertical windows:

```
vim -O file file
```

and `:set scrollbind` in both windows (or add it beforehand to your `vimrc` file)

Answer (score 1):

You may make two separate Vim instances talk to each other using Vim's built-in `--servername` , `--remote-send` and related CLI arguments but it doesn't seem really practicle to me.

What you should do instead is use Vim as it was designed: it had split windows before iTerm or even Mac OS X existed and the other answers here give all the basic infos on how to use this feature.

Plus, your two Vim sessions do not share registers and macros and such.